# Set text in an existing contentcontrol in word 2010 with c# and VSTO

Tags: c#, vsto, contentcontrol, autofill, word-2010

I've been looking and googling around for 4h to find a solution for my problem.

I'm trying to set the text of an defined rich text content control.
For test purposes i defined just one content control (rich text) in the document where i would like to change the text.

```
var docx = Application.Documents.Open(@"D:\BaseDocs\Test.docx");
var all = GetAllContentControls(docx); // Returns all content controls in active document
var one = all.First(); // Select first one --> works
((RichTextContentControl)one).Text = "Test" //Trying to set text --> invalid cast exception
```

I can't set the value of this predefined content control. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: when you look at one what actual type is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I took bookmarks to solve this problem. Thank you all for helping me out.

Answer (score 3):

The real solution of the problem would be to use `one.Range.Text = "Test"`. You can only set the text of a **range** and not of a ContentControl.